# How to compile assets in laravel nwidart?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

In my laravel project I use nwidart.
Each module has its own node_module and webpack.mix.js file. When I run npm run dev on each module, other modules and main vue components does not work and shows this error:

example.js:31589 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
return *webpack_require.e/* import() */(4).then(webpack_require*.bind(null, 44));
}
Reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Here is my Module webpack file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('../../public/');

mix.js(__dirname +'/Resources/assets/js/example.js', 'js/')
   .sass(__dirname +'/Resources/assets/sass/example.scss', 'css/');
```

Main webpack file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-merge-manifest');
mix.mergeManifest();

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is in `example.js:` .?

Comment: My js file in view.

Comment: can u put that code as well in post .?

Comment: I think nothing wrong with code. Because, when I run npm run dev in module, it works.

Comment: ok then remove this post